# How to update .json attribute value converted into string?

Tags: java, json, automation, gson

I have a JSON file which I read from a location and converted it into string as below i.e. A string variable contains exact same JSON as printed below. For some testing purpose I needed it.

So the thing is that I want to update the value of key "MainId". How do I do that?

Here is mine JSON:

```
{ 
 "Entity": { 

    "MainId":"XFG", 

    "AlternateIdentifiers" : [ 

        { 
            "Type":{ 
                "Abbreviation":"ReferenceNumber" 
            }, 
            "Value":"abc" 
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a JSONObject , you have to import the json.org library , put the json in a string and then in the constructor of JSONObject.
So you can navigate the JSON through this new object.

Comment: even after doing that it is adding a new attribute in json rather than updating existing one. But when i try to get the value from json of a specific attribute its working fine